# how to make toggle menu with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make toggle menu with css and JavaScript but the issue is that when click on bars then the navbar
are display but the bars on top are disappear and no option how to close navbar

```
 <a href="#" class="fas fa-bars" id="menu-icon"></a>
        <a href="#" class="logo">flower<span>.</span></a>

        <nav class="navbar">
            <a href="#home">home</a>
            <a href="#about">about</a>
            <a href="#contact">contact</a>
            <a href="#shop">shop</a>
        </nav>
```

```
 let menuIcon = document.querySelector('.fa-bars');
        let menu = document.querySelector('.navbar');

        // Add event listener to the menu icon
        menuIcon.addEventListener('click', () => {
            menuIcon.classList.toggle('fa-bars');
            menu.classList.toggle('open');
        });
```

```
  header .fa-bars{
        display: block;
    }
    header .navbar{
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%; left: 0; right: 0;
        background: #eee;
        border-top: .1rem solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
        display: none;
    }
    header .navbar a{
        padding: 1.5rem;
        margin: 1.5rem;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-top: .1rem solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
        display: block;
        border-radius: .5rem;
    }

    header .navbar.open{
        display: block;
    }
```

this is the code but i don't know how to solve this problem

When did I try to run then the toggle is working for show navbar but there is no option how to close navbar and when click then toggle are disappear

Answer (score 0):

If you are toggling the classList you are changing the current state of the classes of the element you choose. Here is a short [explenation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

In your example you are toggline fa-bars which is the element you bound the click event to. So if you are clicking fa-bars the class gets removed and so it gets hidden. Remove the first statement in your click event and you will be fine.